# JQuery Form Submission Methods Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to capture the value of my input fields on a successful form submission to be emitted through socket.io and used for user notification purposes, but it seems like the three different attempts to trigger my jQuery have failed despite selecting form elements. Can someone point me to where I am going wrong with my selector statements and what would be the best method to achieve this form capture and communication to the socket.io server?

JavaScript File:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    $("#button.blog-comment__form-button").on("click", function(event){
        console.log("Comment Form triggered")
        console.log(event);
        //socket.emit('client-notification', { my: 'successful comment' });
    });

    $("#comment-form").bind('ajax:complete',function(result){
        console.log("Comment successfully submitted");
        console.log(result);
    });

    $("#comment-form").submit(function(event){
        console.log(".submit");
        console.log(event);
    });


});
```

HTML Comment Form:

```
<form action="/app/blog/134jr2n/comment" method="post" name="blogComment" id="comment-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="dsfhj424u2hfi2nf"/>
    <div className="col-md-9">
        <textarea name="comment" class="blog-comment__form-text-area"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3">
        <button type="submit" className="blog-comment__form-button">Comment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try `$("#comment-form").on('submit',function(event){` instead of `$("#comment-form").submit(function(event){`  @cphill

Comment: @Varun thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't have any impact. My form is generated by React.js, would that have any impact on my jQuery trying to locate the form?

Comment: Then the events should be bound to jQuery the elements after `componentDidMount` i guess

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event to the document like:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#comment-form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('It works!');
});
```